# 24v power supply to 24v and a Arduino

Tags: arduino, power-supply, power

I have a Power Supply of 24 volts and 2.5A.

I need something like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Ll2.png

I need a power supply of 24V and almost 1500mA and another of around 8 volts and 500mA (to suplpy an Arduino). It is possible with this connection? Or I nees something like [http://www.amazon.com/LM2596-Converter-Module-Supply-1-23V-30V/dp/B008BHAOQO/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008BHAOQO)

How much the resistors would be?

Thanks!

Comment: You need a 24v to 5V step down regulator.

Answer (score 1):

Using a switch-mode buck converter is the most energy-efficient method of doing what you want.  The reason that I mention energy efficiency is that if you used resistors as per the image that you linked to, you will need to get rid of the excess heat generated.  This amounts to (24V - 8V) * 0.5A = 8 Watts.

The dc buck converter that you linked to is also available on eBay for significantly less than Amazon's price.  In fact, it's available on eBay for less cost than purchasing suitable resistors from Digikey.